# Wicket - Getting broken pipe exception when accessing DB

Tags: spring, hibernate, wicket

In my wicket application I have this service class:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Component
@Transactional
public class DatabaseService {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory; 

    public void save(Message m) {}
}
```

This service class is "injected" into a wicket panel:

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {

    @SpringBean()
    private DatabaseService service;

}
```

It works fine. But if I open the application hours later (server is still running), I receive following error:

```
 java.net.SocketException: Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)
      at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
      at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
      [...]
      at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
      at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3634)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2460)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
      at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4874)
      at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:371)
      at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:328)
      [...]
 (JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:214)
      at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:52)
      at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1525)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:500)
      [...]
      at de.project.database.DatabaseService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8fa0ab80.getMessages(<generated>)
      at WICKET_de.project.database.DatabaseService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$68e55e7c.invoke(<generated>)
      at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
      at org.apache.wicket.proxy.LazyInitProxyFactory$AbstractCGLibInterceptor.intercept(LazyInitProxyFactory.java:350)
      at WICKET_de.project.database.DatabaseService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a9cbdf2b.getMessages(<generated>)
      at de.project.pms.MyPanel.<init>(MyPanel.java:26)
      at de.project.home.projectHome.<init>(projectHome.java:17)
```

Is it connected with the (un)detach mechanismn of wicket?

Comment: Is possible scenario: DB is executing longer query, Wicket component no longer exists (page relaoded)? How long JNDI timeout are defined?

Comment: A wild guess, but: doesn't your query crash Mysql?

Comment: If I press F5 the side is reloaded correctly. I forgot to mention that I use Wicket Security / Authentification. Maybe the session is not valid any more that causes the SQL crash...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL connections usually time out after a period of time. This causes exceptions if you are using a datasource/connection pool and do not use connection validation. From the stack trace you've pasted I see that you are using apache dbcp as a datasource, so I think you should set the following parameters on it:

```
validationQuery, testOnCreate, testOnBorrow, testOnReturn, testWhileIdle
```